# Naming functions after a path

Tags: bash, path, export

I want to wrap a function with its full path.

```
$ pwd
/home/me

$ which pwd
/bin/pwd

$ function /bin/pwd() { 
echo "wrapping pwd" 
command /bin/pwd
} && export -f /bin/pwd

$ /bin/pwd 
wrapping pwd
/home/me

$ bash -c "/bin/pwd"
bash: error importing function definition for `BASH_FUNC_/bin/pwd'
/home/me
```

Is there a way to successfully export functions named after some path? First export does not complain, but the exports in sub-shells do.
The end goal is to set environment variables before launching the actual command.

Answer (score 1):

A function name can only contain alphanumeric characters and underscores, and must begin with an alphabetic character or an underscore.

Comment: So there is no workaround to wrapping the full path of a command in sub-shells?

Comment: @user3298319 You seem to be confusing the concepts of a "function" and a "program living on the file system".  A program needs a full path to find it on the file system.  A function has no reason for a full path, because it's built/added into the shell itself.  On the other hand, when you use a full path, then you are going to get the program from the file system.

Comment: Ok but I don't understand why the export of my full-path function works in the current shell and not in the sub-shell.

Comment: The [posix standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_09_05) says a shell "may allow other characters in a function name as an extension" -- apparently bash allows slashes! Except they're weird enough that inheritance (with `export`) doesn't work right. But it's amazing that they work at all!

Comment: @GordonDavisson You should add that as an answer.